# How to invalidate XML that does not conform to a schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I know this question has been asked multiple times here in StackOverflow and tried all the solution given to those questions. However, in my case the schema I have created only works when I try to validate with the XML that contains an element exist in Schema. Example, I have an XML contains `<Users></Users>` element which exists in my Schema.

What I want is to invalidate all the XML that does not conform to my Schema. So if the XML does have the `<Users></Users>` then the validation should throw an exemption.

Here are the Schemas, I have separated individual by file and namespace:

**Users Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:users"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:cd="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata"
    xmlns:pfl="urn:company:schema:xsd:profile"
    xmlns:usr="urn:company:schema:xsd:users"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata" schemaLocation="company-common-data-schema-1.0.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:profile" schemaLocation="company-profile-schema-1.0.xsd" />
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Document Identifier: company-user-schema-1.0
            Revision history:
            V1.0
                Initial Schema
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Users">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="User" type="usr:UserType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="UserType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="cd:EmailAddressType" />
            <xs:element name="Active" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
            <xs:element name="Profile" type="pfl:ProfileType" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Profile Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:profile"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:pfl="urn:company:schema:xsd:profile"
    xmlns:cd="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata" schemaLocation="company-common-data-schema-1.0.xsd" />
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Document Identifier: company-profile-schema-1.0
            Revision history:
            V1.0
                Initial Standard
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType name="ProfileType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="cd:NameType" />
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="cd:NameType" />
            <!-- remove other elements for brevity -->
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Common Data Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:cdt="urn:company:schema:xsd:commondata"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Document Identifier: company-common-datatype-schema-1.0
            Revision history:
            V1.0
                Initial Schema
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType name="EmailAddressType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:maxLength value="254"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[_\-a-zA-Z0-9'\.\+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](\.?[\-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="NameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Za-z])+))*" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Note: I'm adding these schemas to a resource.**

Here are the XMLs I'm trying to validate:

**XML conform with the Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<usr:Users>
    <usr:User>
        <usr:EmailAddress>john.doe@company.com</usr:EmailAddress>
        <usr:Active>true</usr:Active>
        <pfl:Profile>
            <pfl:FirstName>John</pfl:FirstName>
            <pfl:LastName>Doe</pfl:LastName>
        </pfl:Profile>
    </usr:User>
</usr:Users>
```

**XML that does not conform to the Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foos>
    <Foo>
        <FooEmail>john.doe@company.com</FooEmail>
        <FooActive>true</FooActive>
        <FooProfile>
            <FooFirstName>John</FooFirstName>
            <FooLastName>Doe</FooLastName>
        </FooProfile>
    </Foo>
</Foos>
```

Here are the codes I'm using to validate XML against my Schema:

```
// remove some of the codes for brevity
private static bool ValidateXml(string xmlSrc, XmlReaderSettings xrs, out IList<Tuple<object, Exception>> validationErrors)
{
    var isValid = false;
    var xmlReader = new object();

    validationErrors = new List<Tuple<object, Exception>>();

    try
    {
        using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlSrc))
        using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(xtr, xrs))
        {
            while (xr.Read()) { }
            xmlReader = xr;
        }

        isValid = true;
    }
    catch (Exception xdsEx)
    {

        validationErrors.Add(
            new Tuple<object, Exception>(xmlReader, xdsEx));
    }
    return isValid;
}



private static XmlReaderSettings XmlSchemaReader(
    IEnumerable<string> xmlSchemas,
    out IList<Tuple<object, XmlSchemaException>> validationErrors)
{

    var schemaCollection = new XmlSchemaSet();
    var readerSettings = InitializeDefaultXmlReaderSettings();
    var internalValidationErrors = new List<Tuple<object, XmlSchemaException>>();

    foreach (var xmlSchema in xmlSchemas)
    {
        var iterationValidationErrors = new List<Tuple<object, XmlSchemaException>>();

        var xsdReader = new StringReader(xmlSchema);
        var schema = XmlSchema.Read(xsdReader,
        (obj, eventArgs) => iterationValidationErrors.Add(
            new Tuple<object, XmlSchemaException>(obj, eventArgs.Exception)));

        readerSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
        internalValidationErrors.AddRange(iterationValidationErrors);
    }
    validationErrors = internalValidationErrors;

    return readerSettings;
}

private static XmlReaderSettings InitializeDefaultXmlReaderSettings()
{
    var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
    readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;

    return readerSettings;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It is working with the first given XML example.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  What does "invalidate" mean to you?  By definition, XML that conforms to the rules for valid documents given in a schema (in whatever schema language) is valid against that schema, and XML that does not is invalid against that schema.

Comment: Make it wrong? So if Im going to validate an xml any xml that does not conform should be mark as invalid. Yes that should be the case however it does not it makes all the xml that does not conform to my schema valid and if i tried to validate an xml that follows the schema document and change slighlty one of the element it throws an except that the one of the element is wrong.